# Physically remove vertex in a Graph C

Tags: c, graph

I have a problem in my C program when i try to remove a vertex from my graph in form of adiacency lists. Here is my code:
"Phisically" remove is in simple terms the realloc of the array of lists. I think problem is in the second for but i have no idea, realloc works for me.

Graph struct:

```
typedef struct edge{
    int value; //valore del vertice di arrivo
    struct edge * next; 
    //questa struttura identifica un arco, NON UN VERTICE!!!
    
}edge;

typedef struct graph {
    int nv;
    edge **adj; 
}graph;
```

Delete func:

```
void deleteVertex(graph* G, int vertex) {

//vertex = veritce da eliminare
int i = 0, j = 0;
 
edge * currNode = G->adj[vertex];

//caso lista propria
//svuotiamo la sua lista di adiacenza
while (currNode != NULL) {
    edge* tmp = currNode;
    currNode = currNode->next;
    free(tmp);
}


//riallochiamo il vettore
for(i = vertex; i < G->nv-1; i++) {
    printf("sono nel for i:%d i+1:%d\n", i, i+1);
    G->adj[i] = G->adj[i+1];
}

    
//sempre l'ultima posizione va a null
G->adj[G->nv-1] = NULL;
G->nv -= 1;
G->adj = (edge **)realloc(G->adj, G->nv * sizeof(edge));



//Rimuove l'elemento nelle liste di adiacenza degli altri vertici
for(i = 0; i < G->nv; i++){
    
    edge* testa = G->adj[i];
    if(testa != NULL){
        //Caso elemento in testa
        if(testa->value == vertex){
            G->adj[i] = testa->next;
        }
            //caso elemento in centro
        else {
            edge * scorri = testa;
            while(scorri->next) {
                if(scorri->next->value == vertex){
                    testa = scorri->next;
                    scorri->next = scorri->next->next;
                    
                }
                else scorri = scorri->next;
            }
            
        }
        free(testa);
    }   
}


}
```

Example: number of vertex 5

```
0 :NULL
1 :2-->3-->NULL
2 :3-->NULL
3 :4-->NULL
4 :1-->2-->NULL
```

deleting vertex 2 output (it works):

```
0 :NULL
1 :3-->NULL
2 :4-->NULL
3 :1-->NULL
```

deleting vertex 4 (program crash):

```
0 :NULL
1 :11168960-->11168896->....
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], which anyone can compile and reproduce your problem? Also, try to eliminate any user input and provide both expected and actual output.

Comment: @LuigiV. a [mcve] needs includes as well. It's something that can be copy/pasted/compiled/run without guesswork nor need to stitch pieces of code together. The `main` function is missing here. Please [edit], your output alors is useless.

Comment: BTW: Try to find a video tutorial showing how to step through the code in a debugger. This will make it much easier for you to find the error.

Comment: Close voter: which typo are you refering to?

Comment: Not me, but in many cases, once you extracted the mandatory [mcve], the typo becomes obvious. That's also one of the reasons why it really is mandatory.